# Изменить функцию через условие

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

Нужно чтоб при первом клике бралось ид элемента и сохранялось в переменную, при втором клике бралось ид другого элемента и сохранялось в 2 переменную потом эти данные передавались вот сюда :  var path = finder.findPath(0, 3, 9, 9, grid);

только вместо чисел id (id это координаты клетки) элементов. Потом запускалась функция:  drawPath(path) и значение 2 переменных сбрасывалось на ноль.

должно получится что то типа такого : path = finder.findPath(переменая1, переменная 2, grid); запускаем drawPath(path) сбрасываем значение переменных на 0.

вот код которым я это хотел реализовать:

```
 $(function() {
var informer = false,
    sfId_Start,
    sfId_Target;
var part1
var part2

$('td').click(handleClick);

function handleClick() {

    informer = !informer;

    if (informer) {
        sfId_Start = $(this).attr('id');
        part1 = sfId_Start
        sfId_Target = null;
    } else {
        sfId_Target = $(this).attr('id');
        part2 = sfId_Target
        sfId_Start = null;
    }


    if (part1 > "" && part2 > "") {
        console.log(part1, part2)
        path = finder.findPath(console.log(part1 + ',' + ' ' + part2 + ',' + ' ', grid));
        drawPath(path);
        console.log(part1, part2);
        zero();
    } else {

        console.log("mzf")


    }
    console.log(informer, sfId_Start, sfId_Target);
}

function zero() {
    if (part1, part2 > 0) {
        part1, part2 = null;

    } {
        part1, part2 = null;
    }
}
```

});

вот весь код : http://jsfiddle.net/48u3mx4w/18/

Comment: Этот коментарий тут не нужен. Лучше исправьте и дополните вопрос. И, пожалуйста, постарайтесь делать поменьше опечаток. Так будет больше шансов разобраться в коде.

Comment: Еще было бы неплохо расставить точки с запятой в коде. Конечно браузер и так поймет, но может понять не так как вы этого хотели.

Comment: а можно у Вас поинтересоваться, что Вы делаете?

Comment: @tutankhamun код я почистил и исправил вопрос .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Особо не вдавался в вопрос, но сделать можно так -

```
var Point = function(x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}


var SomeClass = (function(){
    function SomeClass(validator){
        this.validator = validator;
        this.points = [];
    }

    SomeClass.prototype.createPoint = function (x, y) {
        this.points.push(new Point(x, y));

        this.update();
    };

    SomeClass.prototype.update = function () {
        if(this.points.length == 2){
            this.execute();
        }   
    };

    SomeClass.prototype.execute = function () {
        // вот тут Вы получите свою строку
        // которую можно куда-то передать

        var string = this.getString();

        if(string != ''){
            // вот тут передавайте строку куда хотите
        }
    };

    SomeClass.prototype.getString = function () {
        var string = '';
        var length = this.points.length;
        var point;

        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
            point = this.points.shift();

            if( ! this.validator.validate(point)){
                return '';
            }

            string += point.x + ' ' + point.y;
        }

        return string;
    };

    return SomeClass;
})();


var PointValidator = (function(){
    function PointValidator(){}

    PointValidator.prototype.validate = function (point) {
        if(point.x == '' || point.y == ''){
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    };
})();

var pointValidator = new PointValidator();
var someClass = new SomeClass(pointValidator);

grid_clickHandler(event){
    someClass.createPoint(x, y);
}
```

Но Вы должны понимать, что этот код не будет работать если его просто скопировать, его нужно под Ваши нужды приспособить, которые я не понял.